# Jquery validator textbox not equal to default value

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to validate my form as users enter info upon button clicks, not submits. I'm trying to make something that detects if the text in the textbox is the default value. However, it is not working.

I'm not really familiar with the jquery validator. Here is what I have so far.

```
$(document).on("click", "#numexercisesbutton, #submitworkout",
                    function() { //adds exercises 
                        jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value,
                                element, param) {
                            return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
                        }, "Please choose a value!");

                        $("#addworkout").validate({

                            rules: {
                                weightinputboxes: {
                                    required: true,
                                    notEqual: "Enter Weight"
                                }
                            },
                            messages: {
                                weightinputboxes: {
                                    notEqual: "please enter a value"
                                } 

                            }

                            }

                        )




                        if ($("#addworkout").valid()) {

                            addexercises.call(this);
                        }
                    });
```

Not really sure why it isn't working. I was trying to emulate this post: [jQuery Validate: Not default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922168/jquery-validate-not-default-value)

EDIT HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"  type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.validate.min.js"> </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/addworkout.css"  type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/addworkout.js"></script>




</head>
{% extends "masterpage.html" %}
{% block content %}
<body>
<form action="/submitworkout/" method="get" id="addworkout">
<div id="workoutentrycontainer">
<div id="exercisesthisworkout">
<p>Workout Date: </p>
<input type="text" class="required" id="workoutdate" name="workoutdate"> 
<p>Body Weight:</p>
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="weight" name="weight"> 
<p>How many unique exercises</p>
<input type="text" class="textbox required" id="numexercises" name="numexercises"> 
<input type="button" class="button"  value="Add" id="numexercisesbutton"> 
<input type="text" value="Enter Weight" name="weightinputboxes" class="required"> 

</div>
</div>


</form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#..").validate({..})
```

Works on focus moves out the box. u are combining click and blur.

In your code, flow is like:

1. Click on button will activate validation method.
2. After click on button(s), when u type in the textboxes and moves focus out of the box validator will validate the value.

Comment: So i'm not sure what i should change, it works with required: true, just not the extra method I have created.